# Trying to Allocate More Space on Crouton Linux Chromebook

Tags: crouton

so I installed Linux (Crouton) on my Chromebook and immediately noticed I was out of space. The laptop only had 16GB of flash storage. I'm trying to install something via Steam but I want to install it to the USB (actually it's a MSD plugged into a card reader) and not the internal memory. However, when I go into Steam to change my library folder, the USB doesn't appear. Any help?

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE], or more generally [SU].

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. As for DK Bose, I believe that Crouton is a special version of Linux designed to run on a Chromebook. Basically, it's downloaded and installed to the internal memory and can be accessed either by typing 'startxfce4' in a command line or once open by pressing CTRL+ALT+TAB+Forward arrow with the same combination to switch back to Chrome OS but backwards arrow instead of forwards.

Comment: To David, I'm brand new to this community so I apologize if I posted in the wrong area!